# load customer cart in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I'm trying to load a customer shopping cart so I can add products then save the cart.
I tried this but no luck with loading the cart:

```
    $customerCart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->loadByCustomer($idUser);

    $customerCart->addProduct($idProduct,$quantity);
    $customerCart->save();
```

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.ipaste.org/Ivg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you are in the admin, and needing to add an item into the cart (even though the admin already has this functionality), you would do it differently than when you are on the frontend. One key point that is a little confusing in Magento is that a cart is not really what stores the items - the `quote` does. The cart is a wrapper for the quote. If you think about it a little, it really makes sense.

So, to access a customer's quote from the admin, you do it like this:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

If you want to access the customer's quote from the frontend, you would do it like this:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Comment: I tried the admin option but it didn't work for me. What I'm trying to do is an integration of a system with Magento so when a customer in the other system adds a product to the cart an event is triggered with this functionality so the product gets added to the customer's magento cart too.

Comment: Update: it worked partially... I was setting wrong the product; however the code runs successfully but the product doesn't get added to the customer's cart

Comment: I just doublechecked my code and found that the `addProduct` method returns an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`, instead of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`. I generated a test scenario, and found that the above code is *now* functioning.

Comment: I noticed my problem was not loading the customer session and the items appeared in the admin panel but not in the customer view. Thanks

Comment: I am using `$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');`  but in cart product price and subtotal showing 0.